# Porque o System.out.print.ln deste if não é reproduzido

Tags: java

Alguém pode me dizer porque é que o meu código não executa o `System.out.println("");` do final se o if retorna `true` .

```
public static void tabelear (int tabela[][]){


            for(int linha=0;linha < tabela.length; linha++){
                for(int coluna=0; coluna < tabela[linha].length ; coluna++ ){
            System.out.print(tabela[linha][coluna]+"   ");
                if (coluna-1 == tabela[linha].length){
                System.out.println(""); 
            }
        }
```

Comment: Como você sabe que não executa? Ele tá vazio.

Comment: Sim mas não é suposto executar o println , ou seja fazer um parágrafo, ?

Comment: Qual o objetivo deste código?

Comment: Quando que ele deveria fazer um novo paragrafo com aquele 'sout'?

Comment: diegofm isto é um metodo para outras arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quebra de linha não está sendo *printada* porque a condição está errada.

A última coluna da matriz sempre será igual ao tamanho da linha subtraindo um e a condição está ao contrário

```
public static void tabelear (int tabela[][]){
    for(int linha=0;linha < tabela.length; linha++) {
        for(int coluna=0; coluna < tabela[linha].length ; coluna++ ){
            System.out.print(tabela[linha][coluna] + "   ");
    
            if (coluna == tabela[linha].length - 1){
                System.out.println(""); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isso pode ser facilmente simplificado para

```
public static void tabelear2 (int tabela[][]){
    for(int linha=0;linha < tabela.length; linha++) {
        for(int coluna=0; coluna < tabela[linha].length ; coluna++ ){
            System.out.print(tabela[linha][coluna] + "   ");
        }
        
        System.out.println(""); 
    }
}
```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it.](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso211407)

Comment: Obg desculpa pela perca de tempo

Answer (score 3):

Se sua ideia é fazer um novo paragrafo a cada final de linha, poderia fazer assim:

```
for (int linha = 0; linha < tabela.length; linha++) {
    for (int coluna = 0; coluna < tabela[linha].length; coluna++) {
        System.out.print(tabela[linha][coluna] + "   ");
     }
     System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: oh obg nao sabia!